# Switch on time limiter for a solenoid - will this circuit work?

Tags: analog, timer, solenoid

Here is the problem i have: there is an electromechanical door chime (just a solenoid with a rod inside, which hits one brass pipe when switched on, and, propelled backwards by a spring, another when power is turned off). The problem is that it does not have any protective circuit preventing the solenoid from being turned on for too long, which, in worst case, may cause it's overheating and setting on fire. I actually found out that i'm not the only person being aware of such scenario, there is an article (in Russian) on it, they also provide a simple circuit to resolve this problem [image: simple solution]

Hovewer, i tested it on lower voltage components and was not satisfied with the fact that it still lets some current through solenoid and it's "reset time" is relatively great, if you press the button actively. So, i've designed my own solution below.

[image]

It works as expected when simulated in Proteus, hovewer, i understand that simulation sometimes may be far from reality, so, given the fact that i'm a total newbie in analogue circuits, could anybody point out on any design mistakes i made?

(just in case, L1 represents the solenoid, RV2 is used to change switch on time).
Thank you!

Comment: Just build it and see. You'll probably learn more from debugging it.

Comment: @Kotiachiy, is it really a 310 V bell without a low-voltage transformer?

Comment: @transistor Yes, i've looked inside - there is just a solenoid with it outlets connected to screw terminals, nothing more. Its Zamel grs-941m, just if you are interested.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, that's what i was going to do anyways, just wanted to make sure that i did not make any fundamental mistakes, as its HV circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution, if you can use a transformer or small PSU to make 12V then you could use this circuit.
[image: Bell Timer Circuit]

Like your circuit it uses R/C timing. R6 can be varied to change the maximum on time. R3 allows the reset time to be varied. Be careful if you make this too small as some one could still burn the bell out by repeatedly pressing the bell. The advantage of this method is safety, the bell switch is not connected to high voltage mains. Also the bell is operated with AC which it is designed for, rather than DC.
Possible problems to be careful of if you decide to use your circuit.

- Make sure that Q1 cannot overheat due to high dissipation during slow turn off as the gate voltage drops slowly and the device goes into the linear region.
- MOSFETs can have a tendency to oscillate as they switch, particularly with slow transitions. This depends a lot on the device and also on circuit layout.
- If the bell is pressed until it times out, then released, base current of Q2 flows through R2, R1. some current flows out from gate of Q1 and this will cause Q1 gate to go negative (the amount will depend on gate capacitance of Q1). This could mean that Q1 does not get the full voltage when it turns back on, heading to higher dissipation.
- Finally, when the bell push is released, the rectifier will clamp the back EMF from the bell, not allowing to reverse polarity. This may be fine, but could cause the solenoid to move back too slowly to hit the other pipe when released. This will depend on the solenoid and mechanical design of the bell.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Regarding your suggested solution - i cannot use is as the button and bell's wiring is already mounted inside the wall for direct 220v operation, i cannot make changes to it, what i can only do is modify the bell itself. In fact, with some changes the solution i made worked as expected - just had to replace the discharge transistor with 2n4403 (wondering if 2n5401 did require more base current to operate) and pull down it's base to 0V with 3m resistor.

Comment: I am glad you have a working solution, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems. First the bell solenoid in the original circuit is operated with AC. The inductance of the solenoid will cause the current to be lower than in your circuit where you operate it from DC. Second, R1 in your circuit will dissipate around 30W

Comment: Hm.. if voltage drop on it will be 300V (peak), with it's resistance (30k) current should be 10mA, which is 3W of power, right? Regarding reactance of the solenoid - i believe, i'll either add a ballast resistor in series with it, or just connect it in a way the first circuit describes.

Comment: @Kotiachiy, ooops I added a zero! Yes 3W is a lot of heat. I think you can solve both problems by using something similar to the original circuit but better timing element than the C/R.